# Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK -Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I have installed Eclipse Juno.Then I installed ADT plugin.
It even says as below:
"Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed."

But I am not sure whether Android SDK is required to be installed on top of Eclipse Juno.
Its not automatically recognising the SDK path in Windows-->Perferences.
Could someone suggest on this please?

Comment: you need install Android SDK http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/index.html